# Calculate cumulative distribution function from a lis of values in Python

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate  cumulative distribution function in Python for each value in this list;

```
y = 1000, 1012, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019...
```

the following function;

*F = (yi + the previous y values) / Sum of y values*

Example: F for 1014

```
 F = (1014 + 1012 + 1000) / 8111 = 0.3730736
```

I'd like to know how can I apply this function in Python for a large list of y values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

y =  [1000, 1012, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019]

np.cumsum(y)/np.sum(y)
```

Result is:

```
array([0.12328936, 0.24805819, 0.3730736 , 0.4982123 , 0.62347429,
       0.74885957, 0.87436814, 1.        ])
```

Alternatively:

```
import pandas as pd

y =  pd.Series([1000, 1012, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019])

y.cumsum()/y.sum()
```

Result is now `pd.Series` type:

```
0    0.123289
1    0.248058
2    0.373074
3    0.498212
4    0.623474
5    0.748860
6    0.874368
7    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function like this:

```
y =  [1000, 1012, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019]

def cumululative(list_of_values):
    sum_values = sum(list_of_values)
    F = []  
    temp = 0
    for i in list_of_values:
        temp += i
        F.append(temp/sum_values)
    return F

print(cumululative(y))
```

output:

```
[0.12328936012822093, 0.2480581925779805, 0.37307360374799653, 0.4982123042781408, 0.6234742941684133, 0.7488595734188139, 0.8743681420293429, 1.0]
```